# Не работает новое Splash Screen Api - android, java

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, splash-screen

Здраствуйте! Получаю ошибку **android:windowSplashScreenBackground requires API level 31 (current min is 27)** в теме:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Ставил SplashScreen compat library - **implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01'**

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
       minSdk 27
       targetSdk 31
       ...
    }
}
```

Я понимаю что говорит ошибка... Но мне попадался репозиторий, где у человека точно также все сделано и ошибки нет. (У него min. 26) Вроде бы все один в один. Миллион раз перепроверил. (Ладно вру, не миллион, но очень много раз и проблему не обнаружил).

Могу предоставить свой репозиторий с кодом, если нужно.

Comment: Возможно Вы положили этот стиль в общую папку values, а нужно в values-v31 - тогда ругаться не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `android:` - лишнее. Пропишите так:

`<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>`

С остальными атрибутами - аналогично - без `android:`